# Laravel 5.4 and Vue.js 2.0 Emitted value instead of an instance of Error

Tags: laravel

I'm having hard time on this.

My specific error is on this code: If I'll try to remove it everything works but I need to display the data columns. I don't understand why it cause an error.

```
<select>
        <option v-for="column in columns">{{ column }}</option>
    </select>
```

My app.js

```
    import Vue from 'vue'
import DataViewer from './components/DataViewer.vue'

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: {

        DataViewer
    },
    data: {

    }

});
```

My DataViwer.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="dv">
    {{ title }}
    </div>
    <select>
        <option v-for="column in columns">{{ column }}</option>
    </select>

</template>

<script type="text/javascript">

    import Vue from 'vue'
    import axios from 'axios'
    export default {

        props: ['source', 'title'],
        data(){

            return {

                model: {},
                columns: {}
            }
        },
        created(){
            this.fetchIndexData()
        },
        methods: {

            fetchIndexData(){

                var vm = this
                axios.get(this.source)
                .then(function(response){

                    Vue.set(vm.$data, 'model', response.data.model)
                    Vue.set(vm.$data, 'columns', response.data.columns)

                    console.log(vm.$data.columns);
                })
                .catch(function(response){

                    console.log(response)
                })
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

My ajax results:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I had the same warn and I found this decision: http://github.com.proxy.parle.co/ElemeFE/element/issues/4137

```
<el-tag v-for="tag in tags"> 
=> 
<el-tag v-for="(tag, index) in tags" :key="index">
```

Comment: Thanks the only problem is I don't have a parent in `<template><div> //Added the code here!</div></template>`

Answer (score 1):

I faced that error because of a **syntax mistake** in for loop
the problem was the typo issue in src attribute in img tag!

```
<img class="m-widget__img" src="{{article.img_thumbnail}}" alt="">
```

> which is totally wrong! it have to be like:

```
<img class="m-widget__img" :src="article.img_thumbnail" alt="">
```

as you know in these cases we have to bind the parameter to use in that attribute,
so first of all search for similar mistakes...
hope be helpful

Answer (score 0):

To give Vue a hint so that it can track each node’s identity, and thus reuse and reorder existing elements, you need to provide a unique key

```
<option v-for="column in columns">{{ column }}</option>
```

change it to

```
<option v-for="column in columns" :key="column">{{ column }}</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same warn and figure it out that it happen when writing something else outside the loop:

**This is OK**

```
<template>
<table class="responsive-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="no-print" style="width:1%;">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" v-model="selectAll"><span></span>
                </label>
            </th>
            <th style="width:85%">Fecha</th>
            <th style="width:14%">Acciones</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr v-for="list in messages" :key="list.id">
            <td class="no-print" style="width:1%;">
                <label><input type="checkbox" name="print_messages[]" v-model="selected" :value="list.id"><span></span></label>
            </th>
            <td class="view-link">{{list.formatted_date}}</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**This is NOT OK** and through the error "(Emitted value instead of an instance of Error)"

```
<template>
<h1>I AM TRYING TO ADD A TITLE IN HERE</h1>
<table class="responsive-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="no-print" style="width:1%;">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" v-model="selectAll"><span></span>
                </label>
            </th>
            <th style="width:85%">Fecha</th>
            <th style="width:14%">Acciones</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr v-for="list in messages" :key="list.id">
            <td class="no-print" style="width:1%;">
                <label><input type="checkbox" name="print_messages[]" v-model="selected" :value="list.id"><span></span></label>
            </th>
            <td class="view-link">{{list.formatted_date}}</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

** CHECK THE FIRST LINE AFTER OPENING "template" tag

Any clue on this?

Oh, BTW, I am learning VUEJS brute force style... so be nice ;p

Comment: So apparently you only can have ONE child TAG after TEMPLATE. 've just added a DIV wrapping all the content and it just work...

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was writing this:

```
<div :v-if="a>b"/>
<div v-else/>
```

Instead of this:

```
<div v-if="a>b"/>
<div v-else/>
```

Afaik you usually get this error when you have made a syntactic error in your template. It has usually nothing to do with the javascript and logic of your application.